# Count by week between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

I'm trying to show a count by week but I am unsure of how to find the week that isn't showing between effdate and expdat. How do show the week and count shown below? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a calendar table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive query to enumerate the weeks, then join it with the table

```
with cte as (
    select min(effweek) week, max(expweek) max_week from mytable
    union all
    select week + 1, max_week from cte where week < max_week
)
select c.week, count(t.id_num) cnt
from cte c
left join mytable t on c.week between t.effweek and t.expweek
group by c.week
order by c.week
```

(Simplified) **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef330c7a1961d9550e18c854d6b46d02)**:

```
week | cnt
---: | --:
  12 |   2
  13 |   1
  14 |   1
```